# Any diffeomorphism between the Minkowski indicatrix and the Euclidean sphere?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, finsler-geometry

Consider the Finsler Minkowski space $(R^n,F)$ and the Euclidean space $(R^n,||.||)$. Consider the Finsler Minkowski indicatrix of radius $r$, that is $$\Sigma(r)=\{x\in R^n\ :\ F(x)=r\}$$ FYI. The indicatrix of a Monkowski Finsler metric is (topologically) a spherical fiber bundle over $R^n$. Furthermore consider the Euclidean sphere of radius $r$, that is $$S^n(r)=\{x\in R^n\ :\ ||x||=r\}.$$ Now if there exists any diffeomorphism (an injective and surjective map whose inverse is also injective and surjective) $$f: (R^n,F)\to (R^n,||.||)$$ that takes the indicatrix to the sphere?

I mean I am asking about the indicatrix of a Monkowski Finsler metric which is (topologically) a spherical fiber bundle over $R^n$ is diffeomorphic to the sphere in $R^n$?

The only things that I found is the diffeomorphism between the punctured spaces as $$f:(R^n\backslash\{0\},F)\to (R^n\backslash\{0\},||.||)$$ s.t. $f(x)= \frac{||x||}{F(x)} x$ and its inverse $h(x)= \frac{F(x)}{||x||}x$.

Comment: These two submanifolds, the sphere and the Minkowski sphere, are not diffeomorphic. Even the map you wrote fails to be well defined on the light cone, because it collapses it. Plus, which formula for the Minkowski norm are you using? When you talk about an indicatrix do you mean the hyperbolic space or the de Sirtter space?

Comment: Why they are not diffeomorphic? I did not get what you mean and what is the light cone. I am using any Minkowski norm. It is not specific. A Minkowski norm for me is a norm on the n-dimensional real space which depends on the direction. Once you fix the direction you have an Euclidean norm. By indicatrix I mean the sphere related to the Minkowski norm. It is neither hyperbolic nor de Sirtter space.

Comment: @Futurologist: It seems that the OP is using the terminology from [Finsler manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finsler_manifold) - a fact that I do not find obvious and that should have been made explicit in the post.

Comment: @Majid My bad. Confusion. Minkowski norm could be interpreted as two things, as Alex M. pointed out. My initial interpretation was that you spoke about the Euclidean dot product versus Minkowski dot product, used in special relativity theory. It defines a norm that has a zero locus, the light cone. And you have two notions of a sphere in Minkowski space, the two sheeted hyperboloid (hyperbolic space) and the de Sitter space. Your question is about a (Finsler) norm compared to the Euclidean norm.

Comment: Exactly I am asking about  the indicatrix of a Monkowski 
Finsler metric which is (topologically) a spherical fiber bundle over $R^n$ is diffeomorphic to the sphere in $R^n$?

Comment: These augmentations to your question should be edited into the question, otherwise potential answerers will not understand that your question has been refined/clarified in the string of comments below it.

Comment: Now I hope it is more  understandable now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that $F(x)$ is infinitely smooth (or smooth
enough) on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$. It is continuous everywhere because it is a norm. Per your notations, $\Sigma(r) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \,
: \, F(x) = r\}$ and $S(r) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, : \, \|x\| =
r \}$. Fix $\Sigma(1)$. Then there exists a large enough $R>0$
such that $\Sigma(1) \, \subset \, D_E(R) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n
\, : \, \|x\| < R \}$. Consider an infinitely smooth
(rotationally symmetric) bump function
$$\lambda \, : \, \mathbb{R}^n \, \to \,\,\mathbb{R}$$ such that
\begin{align}
&\lambda(x) \equiv 0 \,\,\,\text{ for all } \, x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus D_E(2R)\\
0 \leq &\lambda(x) \leq 1 \,\,\,\text{ for all } \, x \in D_E(2R)\setminus D_E(R)\\
&\lambda(x) \equiv 1 \,\,\,\text{ for all } \, x \in D_E(R)\\
\end{align}
Rotationally symmetric means it has the form $\lambda(x) =
\kappa\big(\|x\|\big)$ for a smooth function $\kappa(s), \,\, s
\in [0,\infty)$ (actually, one can be very specific about the way
$\kappa$ looks). Define another similar bump function by setting
$$\lambda_{\epsilon}(x)  = \lambda\left(\frac{R}{\epsilon}x\right) = \kappa\left(\frac{R}{\epsilon}\|x\|\right) $$ which has the properties
\begin{align}
&\lambda_{\epsilon}(x) \equiv 0 \,\,\,\text{ for all } \, x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus D_E(2\epsilon)\\
0 \leq &\lambda_{\epsilon}(x) \leq 1 \,\,\,\text{ for all } \, x \in D_E(2\epsilon)\setminus D_E(\epsilon)\\
&\lambda_{\epsilon}(x) \equiv 1 \,\,\,\text{ for all } \, x \in D_E(\epsilon)\\
\end{align}
Take $\epsilon > 0$ very small, so small that $D_E(3\epsilon)$ is
entirely contained in the interior of $\Sigma(1)$.

Consider the expression  $H(x) = \big(1-\lambda(x)\big)\,\|x\| +
\lambda(x) \, F(x)$ which by construction is an infinitely smooth function for all points outside the disk $D_E(\epsilon)$. Define the infinitely smooth vector field on
$\mathbb{R}^n \setminus D_E(\epsilon)$
$$Y(x)  = - \, \frac{\nabla H(x)}{\|\nabla H(x)\|^2}$$
where $\nabla$ is the ordinary gradient in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e.
roughly speaking it is the one defined via $\| \cdot\|\,$ ). One
can verify that, due to the way $H$ is constructed,
$\nabla \, H(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus D_E(\epsilon)$ (recall that $\lambda$ was chosen to be rotationally symmetric and the two
norms are convex functions).

Furthermore, define the infinitely smooth vector field $$X(x) =
\big(1-\lambda_{\epsilon}(x)\big)\, Y(x)$$ for all $x \in
\mathbb{R}^n\setminus D_E(\epsilon)$ and $X(x) = 0$ for $x \in D_E(\epsilon)$. Then $X(x)$ is an
infinitely smooth vector field on the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $\phi^t(x)$ be the flow of the vector field $X$, i.e.
$$\frac{d}{dt} \, \phi^t(x) = X\big(\phi^t(x)\big)$$ Moreover, due
to the fact that the vector filed $X$ is bounded everywhere on
$\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. there exists a large enough cpnstant $M>0$ such that
$$\|X(x)\| = \big|\big(1-\lambda_{\epsilon}(x)\big)\big| \, \|Y(x)\| \leq M$$
the flow extends for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. By construction, given $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus D_E(3\epsilon)$ the following relation holds
$$H\big(\phi^t(x)\big) = H(x) - t$$ for $t \in (-\infty, H(x) - 2\epsilon)$.
Indeed, for any point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus D_E(3\epsilon)$  we have that $X(x) = Y(x)$ so whenever $t \in (-\infty, H(x) - 2\epsilon)$
\begin{align}
H\big(\phi^t(x)\big) - H(x) &= \int_{0}^t \, \frac{d}{d\tau} \, H\big(\phi^{\tau}(x)\big) \, d\tau = \int_{0}^t \, \Big( \, \nabla H\big(\phi^{\tau}(x)\big) \, \cdot \, \frac{d}{d\tau} \, \phi^{\tau}(x) \, \Big) \, d\tau\\
&= \int_{0}^t \, \Big( \, \nabla H\big(\phi^{\tau}(x)\big) \, \cdot \, X\big(\phi^{\tau}(x)\big) \, \Big) \, d\tau\\
&= \int_{0}^t \, \Big( \, \nabla H\big(\phi^{\tau}(x)\big)
\, \cdot \, Y\big(\phi^{\tau}(x)\big) \, \Big) \, d\tau\\
& = - \, \int_{0}^t \,\frac{ \Big( \, \nabla H\big(\phi^{\tau}(x)\big) \, \cdot \,  \nabla H\big(\phi^{\tau}(x)\big) \, \Big)}{\|\nabla H\big(\phi^{\tau}(x)\big) \|^2} \, d\tau\\
& = - \, \int_{0}^t \,\frac{\|\nabla H\big(\phi^{\tau}(x)\big) \|^2}{\| \nabla H\big(\phi^{\tau}(x)\big) \|^2} \, d\tau =  - \, \int_{0}^t  \, d\tau\\
& = - t
\end{align}
The phase flow $\phi^t(x)$ is a diffeomorphism for any fixed $t \in 
\mathbb{R}$ and can move any level hyper-surface $H(x) = r_1$ to any level
hyper-surface $H(x) = r_2$ as long as $r_1 > 2\epsilon$ and $r_1 >
2\epsilon$.

Then, by construction $$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, : \, H(x) = 3R\,\}
= S(3R) \,\,\,\,\ \text{ and } \,\,\,\, \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, :
\, H(x) = 1\,\} = \Sigma(1)$$ Set $t_0 = 3R - 1$. Then, again by
construction, $\phi^{t_0}\big(S(3R)\big) = \Sigma(1)$. Then the
map
$$\phi = \phi^{t_0}|_{S(3R)} \, : \, S(3R) \, \to \, \Sigma(1)$$
is a smooth diffeomorphism between the two submanifolds $S(3R)$
and  $\Sigma(1)$ and in fact $$\phi^t(x) \, : \, t \in [0, 3R-1]$$
is a smooth isotopy of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which isotopes
$S(3R)$ to $\Sigma(1)$. To get an ambient isotopy from $S(1)$ to
$\Sigma(1)$, simply precompose $\phi^t(x)$ with a linear
homothetic isotopy that stretches homogeneously $\mathbb{R}^n$,
taking $S(1)$ to $S(3R)$.

Comment: I should say I am impressed! I really like your solution and it sounds ok. But I still need to check some details. I will let you know if it finally works (hopefully) or not.

Comment: @Majid well, it is just a suggestion, however maybe what you have as $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ should be ok too. Basically mapping points between $S(1)$ and $\Sigma(1)$ along the straight lines passing through the origin should define a diffeomoprhism because both $S(1)$ and $\Sigma(1)$ are convex.

Comment: I cannot understand two parts of your solution.
1. How $H\big(\phi^t(x)\big) = H(x) - t$? 
2. And "this is kind of like Morse theory". In fact I do not know that much about the Morse theory. I just know that it is something related to the critical points of the function. I searched but did not find any relation about Morse theory and why $H$ with this property is Morse and then why the flow can be extended! Could you please introduce some materials about those things.

Comment: @Majid 1. The proof is written in the post. The integral there is the derivation of that property. It follows from Leibniz-Newton's formula of calculus (which is a special case of Stock's formula if you wish). 2. Ignore the Morse theory remark. I just mentioned it in case you were familiar with it. It plays no role in the proof whatsoever. Just the technique is the same. In fact, I will erase that remark right now.

Comment: @Majid I am not quite sure however why you were not comforable with your initial idea of mapping say $\Sigma(1)$ to say $S(R)$ by simply drawing straight rays through the origin. As the origin is contained in the interiors of both  $\Sigma(1)$ and $S(R)$, and since both of them are convex surfaces, each such ray will intersect $\Sigma(1)$ at exactly one point and $S(R)$ at one point as well. So this gives you the one to one map between the two surfaces and it is smooth in both directions, hence a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Yes you are right about the relation why H(ϕt(x))=H(x)−t. I was confused! Now another question. You are claiming that the flow can be extended and is defined on whole $R^n$. You mentioned Morse and I thought that it is a result of Morse. The point is I exactly need a diffeomorphism defined on whole $R^n$ that takes the indicatrix to the sphere. How the flow is defined on $R^n$?

Comment: @Majid The vector field is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ and the flow $\phi^t$ is thus defined on   $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ is defined on  $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$. However, the issue is with how far the flow can be extended with respect to $t$. However, in this case, the property $H \circ \phi^t = H - t$ allows you to see that the flow extends with respect to $t$, defining a deiffeomorphism from an open neighborhood of $S(3R)$ to an open neighborhood of $\Sigma(1)$. Basically, you follow the trajectories of the flow from one surface to the other.

Comment: @Majid these trajectories, starting from a neighborhood of $S(3R)$ exist for all $t \in [0, t_0]$ where $t_0 = 3R - 1$ and stretch all the way to a neighborhood of $\Sigma(1)$. It is these trajectories that start from  $S(3R)$ and in time $t_0$ end at exactly  $\Sigma(1)$. That is the diffeomorphism.

Comment: in the text you have written that "for given $x\in R^n$ the flow can be extended for $t\in [0,H(x)]$. The point is that the flow that you first define is on $[0,H(x)]\times R^n\backslash\{0\}$. Yes? Also in the comment you mentioned that we need to extend the flow with respect to $t$. My point is that we need to extend the flow with respect to $x$.

Comment: Let me see if I understood what you are doing or not. The flow defines on $[0,H(x)]\times R^n\backslash\{0\}$. Now you know that you can extend the flow with respect to $t$ and it implies that the flow after extension passes through $x=0$. Yes?
If yes, in the extension how you assure that the flow passes through $x=0$?

Comment: @Majid I think you need to check the notion of a flow of a vector field. Pick a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$. Then, by the existence and uniqueness theorems for systems of ODEs, there exists a solution $x(t) = \phi^t(x)$ of the system $\dot{x} = X(x)$ with initial condition $x(0) = \phi^0(x) = x$ which is defined for $t \in (-\epsilon_x, \epsilon_x)$ a small interval around $t=0$. The question is how far one can extend the interval for $t$. In our case, it can be definitely extended for $t \in [0, H(x)]$ for every given $x$. This interval however varies from point to point.

Comment: Since you want to map $S(3R)$ to $\Sigma(1)$, you need to be able to start your flow from any $x \in S(3R)$ and extend the trajectory $x(t) = \phi^t(x)$ of the vector field $X$ for $t$ so that the trajectory reaches $\Sigma(1)$. Now, for any point $x \in S(3R) = \{x : H(x) = 3R\}$, since $H(x) = 3R$, the trajectory $\phi^t(x)$ is well defined for all $t \in [0, 3R)$. However, as soon as $t_0 = 3R - 1 \in [0,3R)$, the trajectory $\phi^t(x)$ reaches $\Sigma(1)$, i.e. $\phi^{t_0}(x) \in \Sigma(1) = \{ x : H(x) = 1 \}$ because $H\big(\phi^{t_0}(x)\big) = H(x) - t_0 = 3R - (3R - 1) = 1$.

Comment: @Majid Therefore, $\phi^{t_0}\big(S(3R)\big) = \Sigma(1)$. Furthermore, if I pick a very small open $\delta$-neighborhood $N_{\delta}\big(S(3R)\big)$, for any point $x \in N_{\delta}\big(S(3R)\big)$ there is a trajectory $\phi^t(x)$ defined for $t \in [0, 3R - \delta)$ where $\delta$ is so small that $t_0 \in [0, 3R - \delta)$. Therefore, $\phi^{t_0}\big(N_{\delta}(S(3R))\big)$ is a small open neighborhood, call it $N(\Sigma)$, of $\Sigma(1)$. Thus, the smooth map $\phi^{t_0} : (N_{\delta}(S(3R)) \to N(\Sigma)$ is a diffeomorphism between the two open neighborhoods.

Comment: @Majid Since $S(3R)$ is a submanifold of $N_{\delta}(S(3R))$ and $\Sigma(1)$ is a submanifold of $N(\Sigma)$, the map $\phi^{t_0}$ maps the submanifold $S(3R)$ to the smooth submanifold   $\Sigma(1)$, which means that the two submanifolds are diffeomorphic (and in fact ambient diffeomorphic, which is a bit stronger because it is a diffeomorphism between open neighborhoods of the two).

Comment: I am familiar with the concept of flow and my problem is exactly the part that you claim that you can extend the flow for every $x\in R^n$. You can extend the flow with respect to $t$. However you cannot guarantee that any trajectory passes through $x=0$ or at least this is not so clear and it demands more effort to be proved. Your trajectories are not necessarily straight lines that after extension pass through the origin.

Comment: Besides this, suppose that we accept this diffeomorphism. Consider the relation $H(\phi^t(x))-H(x)=-t$ and let $\alpha(t)=H(\phi^t(x))-H(x)$. Let us differentiate the curve. We have $dH(\phi^t(x)).d\phi^t(x)=-1$. So $dH(\phi^t(x)).X(\phi^t(x))=-1$. Let's see what happens when we are close enough to $0$. $dF(\phi^t(x)).X(\phi^t(x))=-1$. Now if this relation is valid when $x$ is very close to $0$ or even equal to it?

Comment: @Majid Show me where I claim the flow can be extended for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$? Where have I written that? I do not need to prove the trajectories go to $0$. I do not need it at all. It is irrelevant. I do not understand why you are looking at $0$? What's there? Neither $\Sigma(1)$ is close to $0$ nor the sphere $S(3R)$ of large radius $R$. Read very carefully what I wrote, draw yourself a picture of what's happening when $n=2$. This is really simple.

Comment: What I am claiming, and what is crucial, is that the flow $\phi^t(x)$ is a smooth map $$\phi : (-\delta, 3R-\delta) \times N_{\delta}\big(S(3R)\big) \to N(\Sigma)$$ such that for any fixed $t \in  (-\delta, 3R-\delta)$ the map $$\phi^{t} : N_{\delta}\big(S(3R)\big) \to \phi^{t}\Big(N_{\delta}\big(S(3R)\big)\Big)$$ is a diffeomorphism and when $t=t_0 = 3R-1 \in  (-\delta, 3R-\delta)$ we get a diffeomorphism between $S(3R)$ and $\Sigma(1)$. In fact, a diffeomorphism between their open neighborhoods $ N_{\delta}\big(S(3R)\big) $ and $ N\big(\Sigma(1)\big)$.

Comment: But my original question is how to define a diffeomorphism from $R^n$ to $R^n$ that takes the indicatrix to the sphere. You several times mentioned that for every $x\in R^n$ and it is interpreted (at least for me) that you are extending in on $0$. Your map is a diffeomorphism from $R^m\backslash \{0\}$ that is not my case.

Comment: @Majid Ah, ok, it is my fault. I guess I have misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to prove that the round sphere is diffeomorphic to the Finsler sphere. That's why I couldn't understand why you didn't want the usual straight line correspondence. Nevertheless, I think from what I wrote it should be very easy to complete the proof to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solution and the taking time. Your idea is interesting and I like it. The point is I am not sure if this solution works for my case because of the justification that I did in the comment (the derivative ...). But I use your suggestion to see if I can solve my question in another way or not.

Comment: @Majid Do not give up on me yet :)... What about now? I edited the answer and constructed what you need. The fix is not too far from what it was before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57711/discussion-between-majid-and-futurologist).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the indicatrix of a Minkowski space is diffemorphic to a sphere.

Let $I$ and $S$ be the indicatrix of a Minkowski (V,F) and the sphere of a Euclidian space, resp. The aplication $f:S\to I$ give by $$v\mapsto \frac{v}{F(v)}$$
is a diffomorphism. For more details vide the Proposition 2.6 on [Javaloyes and Sànches, On the definiton and examples of Finsler metrics].

Comment: Benigno, a diffeomorphism from $R^n$!!!! I already have a nice diffemorphim between these two!